# gRPC JSON transcoding with Any element

Tags: c#, grpc-dotnet

I'm using JSON transcoding in a .NET 7 gRPC service.
A certain element in the proto file is using the Any element:

```
google.protobuf.Any payload = 3 [(validate.rules) = {any:{required:true}}];
```

When I'm sending a request containing the Any element

Request exerpt:

```json
"inputPayload": {
  @type": "type.googleapis.com/myRequestPayload",
  "foo": "bar",
}
```

it gives this response:

```json
{
    "code": 3,
    "message": "Type registry has no descriptor for type name 'myRequestPayload'.",
    "details": []
}
```

I do have another proto with the definition of myRequestPayload.
How can I register this type so that the gRPC service understands the contents of the Any element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't tried it, I'd expect you to set `GrpcJsonTranscodingOptions.TypeRegistry` to a type registry containing the relevant type, e.g.

```cs
var registry = TypeRegistry.FromFiles(MyProtoReflection.FileDescriptor);
services.AddGrpc().AddJsonTranscoding(options => options.TypeRegistry = registry);
```

Where `MyProtoReflection` is the name of the reflection class generated from the proto.

(You could specify *just* the message types you expect to be in the registry, but I'd normally do it via a set of files...)

Comment: Thanks Jon for the quick reply, I added the required reflection descriptors and it's working indeed.
I wasn't aware of these options.